# Fastlane version upload - We're temporarily unable to save your changes. Please try again later

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm trying to upload a new version of my ios app using FastLane. I already have version 1.0 live and now trying to upload a newer version.

On trying to upload I get the following error.

`Itunes connect - We're temporarily unable to save your changes. Please try again later`

```
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/description.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/keywords.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/release_notes.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/support_url.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/marketing_url.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/promotional_text.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/name.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/subtitle.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/privacy_url.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/copyright.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/primary_category.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/secondary_category.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/primary_first_sub_category.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/primary_second_sub_category.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/secondary_first_sub_category.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/secondary_second_sub_category.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/trade_representative_contact_information/trade_name.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/trade_representative_contact_information/address_line1.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/trade_representative_contact_information/address_line2.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/trade_representative_contact_information/city_name.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/trade_representative_contact_information/country.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/trade_representative_contact_information/postal_code.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/trade_representative_contact_information/is_displayed_on_app_store.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/first_name.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/last_name.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/phone_number.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/email_address.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/demo_user.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/demo_password.txt'...
[16:58:43]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/notes.txt'...
[16:58:45]: Activating language en-US...
[16:58:49]: Uploading metadata to iTunes Connect
iTunes Connect temporary error received: 'We're temporarily unable to save your changes. Please try again later.'. Retrying after 60 seconds (remaining: 4)...
```

I haven't made any noticable changes in the app meta data or even the app itself. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this error too and it took me a while to figure it out. In my case the review information .txt files (first_name.txt, last_name.txt) were empty but the information was manually edited with the iTunes Connect web interface for a previous version and copied to the new version. This seems to result in a mismatch. Adding the values to the .txt files solved this for me. I guess this could happen for any other of the metadata. So it would be safer to not touch the metadata in iTunes Connect web interface when using fastlane deliver. The error message should be improved though.

Comment: I had the same issue. Deleting the "review_information" folder solved the issue.

Comment: I also had this issue.  Running "fastlane deliver download_metadata" downloaded the recent changes from the app store and then deliver completed successfully.

Comment: Still helping in 2019. Thank you